# Install 64bit Python on Rapbian with aarch64 Kernel

Tags: raspbian, python, 64-bit

I enabled the aarch64 kernel with `arm_64bit=1` in /boot/config.txt on Raspbian.
After that I tried to upgrade python to its 64-bit version. 
Fist with "apt upgrade" then with building python from source, but with the command `python3 -c 'import platform; print(platform.architecture())'` I still get the output that my version is 32-bit.
Has anyone an idea how to do it properly?

Comment: Have you tried switching out to the 64-bit version of RaspiOS https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/ that has python3 pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

It is not just the kernel which determines what software you can run.  Applications such as `python` depend upon certain system libraries and facilities. Those are part of the OS *userland* -- everything that isn't the kernel -- which for Raspbian/RpiOS also comes in two flavours, 32 and 64 bit.

The 64-bit version is still considered "beta" and you may have problems with things like the camera, but that is what you will have to install if you want 64-bit python.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response!
If I get it right you say, that it's not possible to install a 64-bit programm on RpiOS 32-bit version even if the kernel has been upgraded to aarch64?
So the only solution would be to download a fresh 64-bit image of RpiOS.

Comment: Yes.  It probably isn't worthwhile unless you have some specific reason to *need* 64-bit python.  I doubt the general performance will be significantly better.

Comment: You would only see a benefit if you are using the 8GB Raspberry Pi 4. Since your software would have more available RAM. Programs wouldn't necessarily run faster on a 64-bit OS. They might even run slightly slower.